# Problems with repositories blocking aptitude

Tags: apt, package-management, wine, aptitude

I just switched to Bionic beaver and I have been trying to install Wine. After following the usual steps (wget Wine repository + Release.key etc.), I started to get the following error every time I use apt commands:

```
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Ign:2 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease           
Err:3 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic Release             
404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.112.69 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic 
Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Now I'm stuck and can't use aptitude at all due to the errors. What could be the problem?

Comment: As far as I know, the Wine PPA hasn't released the package for 18.04. What do you mean by 'can't use `aptitude` at all'?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to open /etc/apt/sources.list with your preferred text editor as root and edit the line for your Wine repository so that it reads:

```
deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ artful main
```

At present, nothing is available for Bionic, so you need to tell apt to look for the next best thing, which is Artful. You'll still get whatever the latest version is as per the PPA, though.

After an apt update, you should be able to install the latest version of whichever Wine package you need.